# RuleFinder.findAll only returns 10 results

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

If I call

`ruleFinder.findAll(RuleQuery.create().withRepositoryKey("squid"));`

Only 10 results are called, despite the fact that the active profile has considerably more than this enabled from the squid repository.

Presumably this is an intentional (but undocumented) limit on the number of returned results.

Can this be worked around or is there another way for a server side component to get access to the active rules? The `ActiveRules` interface looks to be batch side only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug. It will be fixed in version 5.6 : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6390.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the number of returned results.
I also had the problem that the rulefinder didn't find all the rules with the specific repository key. However i was able to find the rule with the specific rule key, but that's not really a solution, you would have to find all rules seperatly.

Comment: So findAll is basically just broken?

Comment: Actually rulefinder is deprecated :
http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.4/apidocs/org/sonar/api/rules/RuleFinder.html#findByKey(org.sonar.api.rule.RuleKey)

Comment: Apparently only deprecated for batch use. No replacement for serverside.

Comment: You are right, i haven't found a solution or that there is a bug, the only solution i had is that i would find a specific rule but like i said that wasnt really an option so i added the rules manaully.